# Get class name of generic object

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a program that takes a spreadsheet as input and, if there are any errors, dumps the errors back out onto a separate spreadsheet with the original data as input by the user and the error message.

To hold the errored records and their error messages I have a `Dictionary` object that may contain one of two types of objects as a key. It will either have a `DataRow` object or an Entity Framework model object by the name of `ZipCodeTerritory`.

Since I might have data input errors (ie 111/2/1980 as a date) I needed to create a separate error class that I use to populate the spreadsheet, and I need to convert the `DataRow`/`ZipCodeTerritory` keys into this special error class. However.. before I do that I need to determine which type I am working with. The method I'm using below has not worked, either with a `DataRow` or a `ZipCodeTerritory` object. Anyone know a better way to determine the type of a generic object?

**C#**

```
//Definition of the Dictionary I'm using to hold the errored records/messages
private static Dictionary<object, string> _errors = new Dictionary<object, string>();

//Snippet of code to show how I'm adding one of the ZipCodeTerritory objects
//"record" object is of type ZipCodeTerritory
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.LastUpdateId))
{
    //Add to error list
    _issues++;
    _errors.Add(record, "Missing last update Id");
    continue;
}

//Section of code that tries to separate key/value and determine type
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, string> item in errors)
{
    //Use custom class in case of data errors 
    //resulting from bad input on spreadsheet
    ZipCodeError zip;

    //Determine type and separate key and value
    Type type = item.Key.GetType();
    if (type.GetType().Name.Equals("DataRow"))
    {
        zip = new ZipCodeError((DataRow)item.Key);
    }
    else if (type.GetType().Name.Equals("ZipCodeTerritory"))
    {
        zip = new ZipCodeError((ZipCodeTerritory)item.Key);
    }
    else
    {
        //Code always falls through to this....
        zip = new ZipCodeError();
    }
```

**ZipCodeError**

```
public class ZipCodeError
{
    //Create generic object properties just in case of 
    //typos or any other unforseen input errors from the spreadsheet
    public object ChannelCode { get; set; }
    public object DrmTerrDesc { get; set; }
    public object IndDistrnId { get; set; }
    public object StateCode { get; set; }
    public object ZipCode { get; set; }
    public object EndDate { get; set; }
    public object EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public object LastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public object LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public object ErrorCodes { get; set; }
    public object Status { get; set; }
    public object Id { get; set; }

    public ZipCodeError(){}

    public ZipCodeError(DataRow row)
    {
        this.ChannelCode = row[0];
        this.DrmTerrDesc = row[1];
        this.IndDistrnId = row[2];
        this.StateCode = row[3];
        this.ZipCode = row[4];
        this.EndDate = row[5];
        this.EffectiveDate = row[6];
        this.LastUpdateId = row[7];
        this.ErrorCodes = row[8];
        this.Status = row[9];
        this.Id = row[10];
    }

    public ZipCodeError(ZipCodeTerritory master)
    {
        this.ChannelCode = master.ChannelCode;
        this.DrmTerrDesc = master.DrmTerrDesc;
        this.IndDistrnId = master.IndDistrnId;
        this.StateCode = master.StateCode;
        this.ZipCode = master.ZipCode;
        this.EndDate = master.EndDate;
        this.EffectiveDate = master.EffectiveDate;
        this.LastUpdateDate = master.LastUpdateDate;
        this.LastUpdateId = master.LastUpdateId;
        this.ErrorCodes = master.ErrorCodes;
        this.Status = master.Status;
        this.Id = master.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `type.GetType().Name` returns then?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary of `<Type, object>`? There are quite a few other issues with what you're doing, but that one really stands out. Really, though, if you have two types of data, I can't see any good reason to keep them in the same collection. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `is` keyword

```
if ( item.Key is DataRow )
{
    zip = new ZipCodeError((DataRow)item.Key);
}
else if ( item.Key is ZipCodeTerritory )
{
    zip = new ZipCodeError((ZipCodeTerritory)item.Key);
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `GetType()` in your implementation. You are always getting `RuntimeType` which is the `Type` you get when you call `GetType` on `Type`

```
//Determine type and separate key and value
Type type = item.Key.GetType();
if (type.Name.Equals("DataRow"))
{
    zip = new ZipCodeError((DataRow)item.Key);
}
else if (type.Name.Equals("ZipCodeTerritory"))
{
    zip = new ZipCodeError((ZipCodeTerritory)item.Key);
}
else
{
    ...
}
```